# When using WCF, Function Overloading rule?

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0

I use Windows Communication Services (WCF) in my project.

In my project,

I write the function like below:

```
GetUserNameByUserId(int userId);
GetProductInformationByProductId(int productId);
```

But this naming have been coming more and more complex day by day.

For instance I have 5 parameters to pass to the function, in this case the function name will be like blow:

```
GetStackOverFlowByStackByOverByFlowByIdByStackOverFlow(string stack, string over, string flow, int id, string stackOverFlow);
```

And assume that I want to get with 2 parameters like blow:

```
GetStackOverFlowByIdByStackOverFlow(int id, string stackOverFlow);
```

I want to use function overloading like below:

```
public void abc(int i)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("abc" + i);
}
public void abc(string i)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("abc" + i);
}
public void abc(string i,int j)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("abc" + i + j);
}
```

That is to say, I want to write below functions:

```
GetStackOverFlow(int id);
GetStackOverFlow(int id, string name);
GetStackOverFlow(int id, string name, string StackOver);
.
.
```

Isn't it?
Are there any methodology for that?
Or am I doing right?

I research and find this:
[Function Overloading in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398079/function-overloading-in-wcf)

```
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract(Name = "GetStringWithParam")]
   string GetString(DateTime date);

   [OperationContract(Name = "GetStringWithoutParam")]
   string GetString();
}
```

and he said that

> But i don't prefer it as it is sometimes lead to confusion.

are there any other way?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to write functions `GetStackOverFlow(id, name)` that filter by id AND by name? I assume "id" would return only one object already. How much more can you filter that?

Comment: good approach but dont think only id sometimes one Id can have more than one row so I have to use more filter..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class as a parameter.

```
[DataContract]
public class MySearchSettings
{

    [DataMember]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string StackOver { get; set; }

}
```

and than create a method like this:

```
public GetStackOverflowResponse GetStackOverflow(MySearchSettings searchSettings)
{
    var response = new GetStackOverflowResponse();
    try
    {
        User user = null;
        if (searchSettings == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("searchSettings");
        if (searchSettings.ID.HasValue)
            user = //queryByID;
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchSettings.Name))
            user = //queryByName;
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchSettings.StackOver))
            user = //queryByStackOver;
        response.User = user;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        response.ErrorMessage = String.Format("{0}: {1}",
                                              e.GetType().Name,
                                              e.Message);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I have not included the `GetStackOverflowResponse class` but you get the idea of it.
One of the benefits of this is that you could easily extend the class without breaking functionality of a client when a newer version of your Service is deployed.

Comment: Yeah having some query object is probably they way that I would go.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine and this is how you overload methods in  WCF(using the name property).I dont see a better approach than using the name property to overload methods.